# Как выполнить обновление в БД только тех полей, что были заполнены? Symfony 4, ORM Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine2, symfony4

помогите плз!
Ситуация следующая: существую таблицы в БД, User и связанная с ним Commission. И есть админ панель, где админ выбирает несколько юзеров и переходит на страницу редактирования таблицы Commission, которая содержит 55 полей для заполнения. Все у меня хорошо получается до момента сохранения. Проблема такая: представим что все поля в таблице уже заполнены и мы редактируем лишь некоторые и при сохранении получается так, что заполненые поля перезаписываются (как и должно быть), а те что остались пустыми, естественно перезаписываются так же в БД на пустые, а надо, чтоб они оставались как прежде, если не были тронуты.

Метод сохранения стандартный для symfony 4, вот маленький пример из 5 полей, допустим надо перезаписать информацию в каких то 2х, а остальные 3 НЕ должны перезаписаться, если не были вписаны в инпуты!

```html
$value->setAlfamsc($request->get('alfamsc'));
$value->setAlfamscreg($request->get('alfamscreg'));
$value->setAlfamscreg($request->get('alfasp'));
$value->setAlfamscreg($request->get('alfaspreg'));
$value->setAlfamscreg($request->get('alfaother'));

$entityManager->flush();
```

Спасибо большое заранее!!!

Такой вариант пока только вижу (от неопытности), но это 55 условий.

```html
if (!empty($request->get('alfamsc')) ) {
                    
  $value->setAlfamsc($request->get('alfamsc')); 

}

if (!empty($request->get('alfamscreg')) ) {
                    
  $value->setAlfamscreg($request->get('alfamscreg')); 

}

if (!empty($request->get('alfasp')) ) {
                    
  $value->setAlfasp($request->get('alfasp')); 

}

if (!empty($request->get('alfaspreg')) ) {
                    
  $value->setAlfaspreg($request->get('alfaspreg')); 

}

if (!empty($request->get('alfakemreg')) ) {
                    
  $value->setAlfakemreg($request->get('alfakemreg')); 

}
```

Comment: За симфони не подскажу, но вы можете проверять, если существует значение то сделать set иначе ничего не делать

Comment: И получается надо прописать 55 условий для каждого поля?

Comment: А использовать `symfony/forms` уже нельзя?

Comment: Я если честно от них ушел, они меня частенько стакали в кастомизации, особенно когда использую вместе с VueJS. А symfony/forms позволяют не перезаписывать не заполненные поля?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вам следует использовать CollectionType для построения формы. Тогда всю работу касаемо изменений, на себя возьмёт symfony.